# Forward stream response

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I have one API that is sending me `csv` file.

```
const response = await axios.get(process.env.BE_URI + url, {
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': process.env.X_API_KEY,
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.session.accessToken
    }
  })
```

But, this API should be called from express. So the code is express looks like:

```
app.get('/downoadFile', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await axios.get(process.env.BE_URI + url, {
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': process.env.X_API_KEY,
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.session.accessToken
    }
  })
  // Want to Forward response as a res. What Should I do here?  
});
```

And my JQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/downoadFile',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('data.....', data)
  }
});
```

How can I just forward the whole response?

I appreciate your response!!!

Answer (score 1):

Axios has a request [option](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) called `responseType` - if you set it to `stream` you can pipe the response data the the res-stream:

```
app.get('/downoadFile', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await axios.get(process.env.BE_URI + url, {
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': process.env.X_API_KEY,
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.session.accessToken
    },
    responseType: 'stream'
  });
  response.data.pipe(res);
});
```